# how to convert a string in array respect the spaces

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
$contenuto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lobortis condimentum commodo. Duis dui dui, rutrum et lacinia sit amet, lacinia in nulla.";
```

I need to break it into an array of substrings with a limit of 20 characters, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Lorem ipsum dolor ";
    [1] => "sit amet, ";
    [2] => "consectetur ";
    [3] => "adipiscing elit. Ut ";
    [4] => "lobortis condimentum";
    [5] => "commodo. Duis dui ";
    [6] => "dui, rutrum et ";
    [7] => "lacinia sit amet, ";
    [8] => "lacinia in nulla.";
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string_parsed = wordwrap($contenuto,20,"|",false);
$array = explode("|",$string_parsed);
```

`wordwrap` function allows us to wrap long text into lines at given character counts (in this case it is 20), you can specify the break char yourself (I've given "|" for splitting), and the last value "false" is meaning that it shouldn't break the word if it reaches the character limit.

Comment: +1, a little explanation would have helped OP to understand more clearly

Comment: The code is nice and succinct, but I'm with Ibrahim on explaining it a bit more.  +1 for code alone.